# How to set a column value according to another column value Trigger statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

Imagine there are two columns in a table; weather and tool

```
WEATHER TOOL 
sun
autumn 
rain
```

if weather = sun, then the tool should have value 'no umbrella' also if weather = autumn, then the tool should have value 'no umbrella'
however if weather = rain, then the tool should have value 'umbrella'

The end table should be generated using trigger or during insert statement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER "UPDATE_TOOL" 
before insert on "UPDATING_TOOL_TABLE"
for each row
begin
IF WEATHER = 'sun' THEN 
    SET TOOL = 'no umbrella';
ELSE IF WEATHER = 'autumn' THEN
    SET TOOL = 'no umbrella'; 
ELSE IF WEATHER = 'rain' THEN 
    SET TOOL = 'umbrella'; 
END IF; 

end;
 /
ALTER TRIGGER "UPDATE_TOOL" ENABLE;
```

Please have a look on the Trigger statement I have created, which doesn't work. I am working in ORACLE SQL.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle 11g+, you don't need to actually store the value.  You can generate it on the fly:

```
alter table UPDATING_TOOL_TABLE
    add tool generated always as (case when weather in ('sun', 'autumn') then 'no umbrella' when weather in ('rain') then 'umbrella' end);
```

EDIT:

As for your trigger, I would expect something like:

```
begin
    select (case when :new.weather in ('sun', 'autumn') then 'no umbrella' 
                 when :new.weather in ('rain') then 'umbrella'
            end) into :new.tool
    from dual;
end;
```

or:

```
begin
    :new.tool := (case when :new.weather in ('sun', 'autumn') then 'no umbrella' 
                       when :new.weather in ('rain') then 'umbrella'
                  end);
end;
```

Comment: Can this code go in Trigger statement between begin and end;

Comment: @GordonLinoff Why add sql into pl/sql unnecessarily (thus introducing context switching)? This could be done as a case or an if statement; no need to select from dual. Or even a case expression, such as `:new.tool := case when ... end;`

Comment: @Boneist . . . A bad habit on my part.

Comment: @GordonLinoff shh, don't tell anyone, but... me too! It's taken me yonks to recognise that I was doing it, despite my campaigning for single DML statements instead of cursor for loops. \*hangs head\*

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Hi, I have a question to extend the answer. What if  there were other columns naming tool_1, tool_2, tool_3 that is affected same way as the column 'tool'. Would it be appropriate to create different triggers for each even they do the same action and look at the column 'weather'. or is there a way where I can refer in a single trigger?

Comment: @JohnSmith . . . I don't understand your question.  If the table has multiple columns, then a single trigger can work on all of them.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, thanks of replying back. I solved this issue, you are right a single trigger worked.